# How to Pass Future<List<int>> function to another Dart files

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I am new in this Flutter, I want to get this data from **asynchronous Future<<List>** to another Dart files. This function return a **ByteData** that I want to add in another dart files in order to create a PDF file with an **Image** and a **datagrid**. This function is placed inside a *Stateful Widgets*. In order to access the return value or data of this function, how to write the code in another Dart Files so I can add the image to the PDF functions?

This is the code that I've created:

```
class CathodicColumn extends StatefulWidget {
  const CathodicColumn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CathodicColumn> createState() => _CathodicColumnState();
}

class _CathodicColumnState extends State<CathodicColumn> {
// Key State for Column Chart
  late GlobalKey<SfCartesianChartState> keyChart =
      GlobalKey<SfCartesianChartState>();

// Initiate State
  @override
  void initState() {
    loadCathodicData();
    keyChart = GlobalKey<SfCartesianChartState>();
    super.initState();
  }

  // Dispose Data
  @override
  void dispose() {
    chartData!.clear();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Overrides
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildCathodicColumnChart();
  }

  Column _buildCathodicColumnChart() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SfCartesianChart(
          key: keyChart,
          plotAreaBorderWidth: 1.0,
          title: ChartTitle(text: 'Cathodic Voltages to Time Column Charts'),
          tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
          legend: Legend(
            position: LegendPosition.bottom,
            isResponsive: true,
            isVisible: true,
          ),
          primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
            edgeLabelPlacement: EdgeLabelPlacement.shift,
            title: AxisTitle(text: 'Time (hourly)'),
            intervalType: DateTimeIntervalType.hours,
            majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
            isVisible: true,
          ),
          primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
            edgeLabelPlacement: EdgeLabelPlacement.shift,
            axisLine: const AxisLine(width: 0),
            labelFormat: '{value} DCV',
            majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(size: 0),
          ),
          series: _getCathodicColumnSeries(),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: defaultPadding * 1.2),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: saveFileAsPdf,
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            maximumSize: const Size(200.0, 50.0),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: const [
              Text("Export to PDF"),
              Spacer(),
              Icon(Icons.picture_as_pdf_outlined),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  List<ColumnSeries<DataCathodic, DateTime>> _getCathodicColumnSeries() {
    return <ColumnSeries<DataCathodic, DateTime>>[
      ColumnSeries(
        name: 'TR Area DWP Voltages',
        dataSource: chartData!,
        xValueMapper: (DataCathodic cathodic, _) => cathodic.timestamp,
        yValueMapper: (DataCathodic cathodic, _) => cathodic.voltage,
      ),
      ColumnSeries(
        name: 'Mile Area 22',
        dataSource: chartData!,
        xValueMapper: (DataCathodic cathodic, _) => cathodic.timestamp,
        yValueMapper: (DataCathodic cathodic, _) => cathodic.voltageLoc2,
      ),
      ColumnSeries(
        name: 'Mile Area 34',
        dataSource: chartData!,
        xValueMapper: (DataCathodic cathodic, _) => cathodic.timestamp,
        yValueMapper: (DataCathodic cathodic, _) => cathodic.voltageLoc3,
      ),
      ColumnSeries(
        name: 'Mile Area 50',
        dataSource: chartData!,
        xValueMapper: (DataCathodic cathodic, _) => cathodic.timestamp,
        yValueMapper: (DataCathodic cathodic, _) => cathodic.voltageLoc4,
      ),
      ColumnSeries(
        name: 'Mile Area 68',
        dataSource: chartData!,
        xValueMapper: (DataCathodic cathodic, _) => cathodic.timestamp,
        yValueMapper: (DataCathodic cathodic, _) => cathodic.voltageLoc5,
      ),
    ];
  }

Future<List<int>> readImageData() async {
    // Convert Charts to Images
    final ui.Image data = await keyChart.currentState!.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);

    // Creates Image from Chart with format PNG
    final ByteData? bytesImage =
        await data.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

    // Return the Image
    return bytesImage!.buffer.asUint8List(
      bytesImage.offsetInBytes,
      bytesImage.lengthInBytes,
    );
  }
}
```

I want to send the return value of the code above to another Dart files, so the **Converted Image** in the ***readImageData() function*** can be added to another PDF Files which includes Chart Images and DataGrid.

Can you help me to write the correct codes please? Thank you!

Comment: For now where you are using thi code and for what purpose?

Comment: I am using this code in order to convert the Chart into a bitmap image and exported it to PDF files.

Comment: i didnt get it, if its a function and not a local function, you can call it in any file.

please provide more code , where did you put that code, and where do you want to use it.

Comment: I have edited my questions, if you have another questions, please tell me so I could give you another explanation. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling the PDF function in another page, you can create a variable with the `readImageData()` function, something like this:

```
Uint8List imageData = await readImageData();
```

And then pass the value to the new screen

```
Navigator.push(context,
 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage(data: imageData)));
```

Example of SecondPage

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Uint8List data;
  const SecondPage({required this.data, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}
```

You can also get the returned value of `readImageData()` by adding `.then` after you await it and do something with the returned value.

```
await readImageData().then((value) {
// Do something with the value

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers and I do really appreciate it. Unfortunately, I don't use the Navigator Push. I just want the return value of the readImageData() can be passed to the Second Page so I could add it to the PDF files. Is there any methods that you know to help me solved this?

Comment: In that case, I think state management in Flutter might be what you are looking for. It allows variable to be access within the App's lifecycle. Unfortunately, I am only familiar with Riverpod, but I am happy to help if you have any trouble while trying it out.

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I'll read it.